# Javascript: Print on HTML browser the updated GPS value on a new line after 1 second interval

Tags: javascript, html, django, geolocation

How do I print on HTML browser the updated value of the `watchPosition()` or `getAccurateCurrentPosition()` method on a new line after every 1 second interval?

The updated value consists of *Time | Latitude | Longitude | Accuracy* to be shown on the HTML browser.

Below is my code which only prints the location to the browser only once. How could I modify this code?

I used a variation of `getCurrentPosition()`, the `getAccurateCurrentPosition()` to return a better result below.

Would it be possible to insert a timer and loop the code through?

How could I prevent the HTML page from erasing the previous lines of GPS result and only add new lines to the browser?

Thank you for any assistance, I sincerely appreciate  it.

location.html

```
<p>Click the button to add coordinates.</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()" class="btn btn-primary">Get Your Location</button>
<p id="result"></p>

<form method='POST' action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>{{ form | crispy }}</p>

{% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit" id="btn_submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```

script.js

```
function progress(position) {
  $("#result").text(`In progress. Please wait for 15 seconds.`);
}

function error(err) {
  console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
}

function showPosition(position) {
  console.log(position);

  var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  var accuracy  = position.coords.accuracy;


  $('#id_latitude').val(latitude);
  $('#id_longitude').val(longitude);
  $('#id_accuracy').val(accuracy);

  $("#result").html(`Latitude: ${latitude}<br>Longitude: ${longitude}<br>Accuracy: ${accuracy}`);
  $("#btn_submit").attr("disabled", null);
}

navigator.geolocation.getAccurateCurrentPosition = function (geolocationSuccess, geolocationError, geoprogress, options) {
    var lastCheckedPosition,
        locationEventCount = 0,
        watchID,
        timerID;

    options = options || {};

    var checkLocation = function (position) {
        lastCheckedPosition = position;
        locationEventCount = locationEventCount + 1;
        // We ignore the first event unless it's the only one received because some devices seem to send a cached
        // location even when maxaimumAge is set to zero
        if ((position.coords.accuracy <= options.desiredAccuracy) && (locationEventCount > 1)) {
            clearTimeout(timerID);
            navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
            foundPosition(position);
        } else {
            geoprogress(position);
        }
    };

    var stopTrying = function () {
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
        foundPosition(lastCheckedPosition);
    };

    var onError = function (error) {
        clearTimeout(timerID);
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
        geolocationError(error);
    };

    var foundPosition = function (position) {
        geolocationSuccess(position);
    };

    if (!options.maxWait)            options.maxWait = 10000; // Default 10 seconds
    if (!options.desiredAccuracy)    options.desiredAccuracy = 20; // Default 20 meters
    if (!options.timeout)            options.timeout = options.maxWait; // Default to maxWait

    options.maximumAge = 0; // Force current locations only
    options.enableHighAccuracy = true; // Force high accuracy (otherwise, why are you using this function?)

    watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(checkLocation, onError, options);
    timerID = setTimeout(stopTrying, options.maxWait); // Set a timeout that will abandon the location loop
};


function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getAccurateCurrentPosition(showPosition, error, progress, {desiredAccuracy:10, maxWait:5000});
  } else {
    $("#result").text("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(yourFunction, 1000);
```